# Are all contour lines of the Shannon entropy on the probability simplex closed?

Tags: functions, parametric, entropy

The state of a trit $$\{p_1,p_2,p_3=1-p_1-p_2\}$$ can be represented as a triangular simplex. The centre of the simplex is the maximally mixed state $$m=\{\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}\}$$. And the pure states are the three corners. If I plot the Shannon entropy $$H(s)=-\sum\limits_{s\in\{0,1,2\}}p_s\log\left(p_s\right)  $$as a contour map on this, I get something like
[image]

Apologies, I can't plot it without the simplex being skewed, but imagine it as an equilateral triangle. States on the same contour have the same entropy.

My question is: Is there an orbiting contour for all states (except the pure states) or is there a subset of states with an orbiting contour (as shown) whereas there are other sets of states whose entropy contour touch the sides? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by an orbiting contour? That the contour forms a closed line?

Comment: yes - I am asking if each contour forms a closed line or if some of them end on the edges of the simplex. Thanks

Comment: On second thoughts, it would make more sense that all states are on a closed contour except the pure states $(1,0,0)$ etc, and the embedded bit states $(p,1-p,0)$ which are related by permutations of labels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entropy function is strictly concave, has unique maximum $\log 3$ at the center, and its restriction to the boundary segments is also strictly concave with unique maxima at $(0, 1/2, 1/2)$ and the permutations, the value at each of these 3 points being $\log 2$.  Thus the boundary states (where at least one $p_i$ is $0$) have possible entropy values between $0$ and $\log 2$, while the entropy between $\log 2$ and $\log 3$ is only achieved in the interior. The higher values give closed contours, the lower give "3 segments"-type contours.

Here's how it all looks:

[image: Graph of entropy function]